# Custom fields for taxonomies with custom value for each post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-meta

I really don't know if this is possible or not, but i can accept a alternative solution too. Here is what I gonna do:

I have a barbershop post type, this cpt has a taxonomy called service. Well, no problem so far. Every barbershop I register, has different services, but every service in every barbershop has a different price, right?

Is this something I can implement in wordpress? I want to do it with custom post type(barbershop), taxonomies(services) and taxonomy metadatas(price).

If this is possible with these wordpress concepts, I want to know how. But if you have another solution to implement this or you think it's not possible at all, I'm glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. Ofcourse you can do it, but that doesn't mean it's a great way to do it, or the fastest or easiest way.

You could give every barber shop its own term that has a price, but then you gain a whole host of new problems.

Instead, lets retreat to the fundamentals and rethink things.

- Post meta is for details about an individual post
- Taxonomies are for grouping, filtering, searching, querying.

So first, are the prices of services individual to a barber shop? Yes! They should be post meta

But do we want to flag barber shops as offering a service? Yes! So use a taxonomy

So now we have:

- A Barber CPT
- A taxonomy that stores which services they provide
- Each barber post has meta values that detail the price of said service at the barber shop ( also known sometimes as custom fields )

I would also recommend adding a taxonomy for how expensive the place is, e.g. when you see options such as `$`,`$$`,`$$$`,`$$$$`, or `1-10`,`11-20`,etc in filters. Querying the price directly and letting the user type in an exact value is possible but very expensive and slow ( post meta is designed for fetching details about a post when you already know which post it is, taxonomies are for when you don't know the post ).

So for example, if you have a service named "Beard trim" and the terms slug is `beard-trim`, why not add a custom field named `price-beard-trim` and store a price in there?

Comment: I have to many services, is that a good idea to add a price custom field for everyone of them? Can it be dynamic to just add the price field for services I need, while writing the post?

Comment: Unless you have tens of thousands of services I doubt it will be an issue, besides, you need to add a price for every single one anyway, barbers don't standardise prices and each Barber has unique prices